# Using predicates find strings begining and ending with A

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nspredicate

I am able to find all the values from an array containing string beginning and ending with `A`.

I can use `-hasPrefix` and `-hasSuffix` from `NSString` class.

But I am not finding any way to find the same using `NSPredicate` class.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see my answer it will helps you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one may be it helps you,

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like [c]'A*A'"];
    NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@" AhfjA ", @"test1", @"Test", @"AntA", nil];
    NSArray *b = [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
    NSLog(@"%@",b);
```

Comment: Why this is not working, please check  NSArray *names=@[@"John",@"Anoop", @"Superman",@"Gilly",@"Adams",@"Mike",@"Forina",@"Serena", @"aDolf"];
    
    NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like [c]'A*A'"];
    NSArray *ends=[names filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"->%@",ends);

Comment: i verified this one working fine. NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"John",@"Anoopa", @"Supermana",@"Gilly",@"Adams",@"Mike",@"Forina",@"Serena", @"aDolf",nil];

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: This predicate finds all names that start with an A ***and*** end with an A, as formulated in the question. Your code finds names starting with A ***or*** ending with A. Your code also returns duplicate results for names that start and end with an A.

Comment: XCOde sucks... needed to clean :(

Comment: @MartinR: Yes I agree Sunny answer is better then me :)

Comment: my code will  give the names which start and end with the letter A.